# Was Rhûn (the East) based primarily on the lands of Asia?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, middle-earth

In Tolkien’s Middle-earth; was Rhun based primarily on Asia? I think there are Bilbo references to this in *The Hobbit*, but I do not know certainly. Does anybody know the answer of this topic?

Comment: According to The One Wiki to Rule Them All (a fandom wiki and hence not necessarily a 100% credible source), Rhûn is inhabited by Easterlings, which seem inspired by Middle Eastern cultures. There are also quite a lot of Dwarves living in Rhûn.
https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Rhûn

Comment: Given Rhun just means "East" then yes: https://middle-earth.xenite.org/is-rhun-a-part-of-middle-earth/

Comment: The appendices describe an Easterling invasion of Gondor in which the invaders travel on yurts called "wains", which make them sound like a steppe culture.

Comment: @tbrookside Did you really mean "[yurts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yurt)"? They're not a type of conveyance.

Comment: A "wain" is a wagon, so that's the conveyance.  I read that as intending to say "travel on yurt-covered wains."  And yurts on wheels [is a thing](https://www.ancient.eu/image/11226/wagon-yurt-or-khibitkha/).

Comment: @DavidW --- but somehow I don't think Gondor's northern army would have been defeated by men riding those.

Comment: @IanThompson They don't _fight_ from them, obviously.  They'd be horsemen, light cavalry, like the Mongols.  The yurts would be their base and resupply; instead of setting up tents to encamp, they'd just park the yurts.  Just like a heavy cavalry doesn't drag their baggage train into battle.

Comment: The history of Europe from the very earliest days for which we have information is one wave of invader from the steppe after another: Celts, Germans, Huns, Magyars, Scythians, Mongols, Turks and many others. It seems pretty clear that Tolkien's Easterlings are taken very directly from them.

Answer (score 2):

We don't know that much about Rhûn but I think it's safe to say that it is Middle-earth's equivalent to central Asia. The Wainriders seem to be inspired by cultures like Scythians and how they fight wars (which was discussed in the comments under the question).

Also, In the early drafts of *The Hobbit* Bilbo does mention China existing in the east:

> to the last desert in the East and fight the Wild Wireworms of the Chinese

Source: J.R.R. Tolkien, John D. Rateliff (ed.), The History of The Hobbit, Mr. Baggins, The First Phase, "The Bladorthin Typescript", p. 40

Answer (score 0):

There was an interview of Tolkien to clarify the topic.

Excerpts from: Henry Resnick, “An Interview with Tolkien [March 2, 1966],” Niekas No. 18 (Late Spring 1967).

(“Rhun is the Elvish word for ‘east.’  Asia, China, Japan, and all the things which people in the west regard as far away.  And south of Harad is Africa, the hot countries.” (Resnick, “An Interview,” 41))

Comment: Note that for a time later in life (after LotR was written) Tolkien tried to make his world markedly more "real" in the sense of making it consistant with science. (Happily, These later musings and re-writings were not allowed to infect LoTR or the Silmarillion.  We should not assume that a later interview necessarily reflects Tolkien's meaning when he wrote the book.

Comment: Tolkien clearly said where he thought Rhûn and southern Harad were in his interview. I don't need to think too much other way.